# How do create an app that install a VPN profile?

Tags: ios, vpn, profile

I need to create an App that install a VPN existing profile like the app [1.1.1.1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1-1-1-1-faster-internet/id1423538627?mt=8) on the iOS store.

This app basically connect to a VPN by asking the user to install an embedded VPN profile. I cannot find any Apple documentation about that. Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an [`NEVPNManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager). See ["What's New in Network Extension and VPN"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/717) from WWDC 2015.